# OS X groups seems to allow character classes to repeat many times by default

Tags: regex, macos, shell, grep

I am trying to grep a text file for somethings, and I noticed some odd behaviro on OS X. I feel that I have a pretty solid grasp on regular expressions, but maybe I don't know as much as I think. So, I apologize if the answer is obvious.

Each line of my text file has this format:

```
<number> <number> <text>
```

So just to start, I want to see if I could match lines starting with a 1:

```
grep "^1" dataset.txt
```

However, it seems grepped match any line starting with 1, 11, 111, etc. This is just incorrect I think. EDIT: grep is matching `1`, `11`, `111`, etc. This was causing some confusion. My problem is that grep is matching too many 1's, not that it is returning lines starting with 11.

Next, I wanted to see what would happen if I searched for any line starting with any digit:

```
grep "^[0-9]" dataset.txt
```

This matched the whole number at the start of each line, such as `130380`, which is also incorrect. I tried this to see if I could only match the first digit in the line:

```
grep "^[0-9]?" dataset.txt
```

This pattern returns nothing. I also tried specifying `-P` to use perl style regular expressions and got this:

```
grep -P "^[0-9]" dataset.txt
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

Clearly `P` is in the list of arguments, although I read the man page on my system, and `-P` was not listed. Does anyone know why grep is acting like this?

Thanks

Comment: It is totally how regexes should work. `111` starts with `1`. If you want it to match lines with only 1 digit, use `^[0-9]$`, if it starts with a digit, then something else, use `^[0-9][^0-9]`.

Comment: Sure, `111` starts with `1`, but it is specifically matching `111` by the color highlighting, which is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, so you're not worried about the match, but _only_ the color highlighting? Yes, that would be in error in my mind (my 'nix `grep` just highlights the first `1` of a `111` sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `grep "^1" dataset.txt`
>   However, it seems grepped match any line starting with 1, 11, 111, etc. This is just incorrect I think.

This is **expected behavior**: you're asking for lines whose *first* char is `1`, without further constraining what comes after.

If, by contrast, you don't want to constrain *matching*, but instead want to constrain the *output* by only printing the *matching part* of the line, you must use `grep`'s `-o` option.

**Update**: Turns out that the OP was referring to the `--color` option's behavior: `--color` is supposed to color (highlight) the matching part of every matching line, but does so incorrectly due to a **bug** - as of `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` (OS X 10.9.2).
.

> Clearly P is in the list of arguments, although I read the man page on my system, and -P was not listed. Does anyone know why grep is acting like this?

`-P` (Perl-style regexes) are indeed NOT supported on OSX - what you see is a **typo in the error message** (it should be `-p` (lowercase!), an entirely different option - see `man grep`).

> `grep "^[0-9]?" dataset.txt`
>   This pattern returns nothing.

This is **expected behavior**: OSX grep defaults to *basic* (aka obsolete) regular expressions, which require escaping `?` as `\?`.
If you want to use extended (aka *modern*) regular expressions - where such escaping is not needed - invoke `grep` either as `egrep` or with the `-E` option.

Comment: I know that any line starting with 1 should be returned, but it is matching `111` (by the color highlighting) which is the incorrect behavior

Comment: Here is an example of what is matched:

`grep -E "^[0-9]?" test.tst`

`<12345> abc`

Note, I added the `<>` to show what was matched.

Comment: @Max: If you only want to print the _matching part of the line_, you must use `-o`. By default, `grep` prints the _entire line_ - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I still I wasn't clear. I guess the issue is the color highlighting. But thanks for the -E suggestion. That seems to work, and I guess I'll just have to get used to the color highlighting on things that aren't matches.

Comment: @Max: Got it. Sounds like a bug. Perhaps file a report with Apple / FreeBSD.